# MVC 5 - Roles - AuthorizeAttribute outdated

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, claims-based-identity, asp.net-roles

In my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25742310/mvc-5-roles-isuserinrole-and-adding-user-to-role) i asked how to check/add user roles, but now i face another problem.
Since microsoft moved to the new Identity 2.0, AuthorizeAttribute doesn't work anymore.

Is there any substitute filter for the Authorize?

**EDIT:**

I've made some tests and [Authorize(Users = "SOME_ID")] works, but not [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")].

And i verified if the user was really in that role (Admin)

Comment: `Authorize` works fine. Internally it is checking the claims cookie for the existence of a role. You should post your code where you give the user his claims and make sure the roles are in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually  [Authorize(Roles = "ROLENAME")] working fine.

Check your userRoles (or AspNetUserRoles) table for assigned roles for the id your have used that is SOME_ID according to your question. If not you have to correctly assign role "Admin" to the users when you create users.

hope this helps.

Comment: Well, i messed up with the Indentity 2.0...
I tried to install identity 1.0 and some methods stopped working. When i removed the messed up files i also deleted the old asp tables and forgot to populate the new ones.

Comment: I noticed the role name is case sensitive too