# Cant check if User is in a Role ASP.NET Identity 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So i'm trying to build off Identitie's individual authentication system but every check I do for a Role of the User returns with false, here is my controller for logging in which I would redirect the user if I could do a role check.

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                var r = Roles.IsUserInRole( "Trainer");
                var y = User.IsInRole("Trainer");
                return RedirectToAction("index", "Home");
```

Every time i've run this both of these methods(vars r and y) return false. I have enabled RoleManager with
 `<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"/>`
And I for sure have a Role "Trainer" since I run this to make a test user
`await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, "Trainer");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you mix `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` with `System.Web.Security` which is not working as expected.

I can't actually try it right now, but using the [`UserManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613290%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) should work better. Something like

```
SignInManager.UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(model.Email, "Trainer");
```

[See this SO answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25742310/mvc-5-roles-isuserinrole-and-adding-user-to-role)

Comment: Yeah I wasn't trying to use both methods, was just trying each one to see if one would work, however UserManager did it for me, thanks